# Filter Query Layer with Field from a Table in a Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, query-layer

ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2

Is it possible to use the column of table in my Project to filter a query using the [make query layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-layer.htm) tool?

I have a table of events in my project with a `location_id` column, and I want to left join in my Locations table by `location_id` from different database. I want to only pull in locations that exist inside of my event table in the project so that I'm not loading the entire locations table.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM location_tbl
WHERE location_tbl.id IN (<id_column_of_table_in_my_Pro_Project>)
```

I see this [doc here about query parameters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/define-parameters-in-a-query-layer.htm), but I don't see anything about passing in a column from an existing table as a parameter.

The data comes from two different SDE connection files to an MS SQL Server database.

Comment: If the objects are in the same source workspace, you could do a subquery (`WHERE col1 in (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col2 = testcase)`). Without more info about the data sources, it's difficult to assist.

Comment: Added to question. It's two different SDE connections. As far as I am aware, I don't think it's possible to query two different databases at the same time.

Comment: You can do a Join, but it's *way* more efficient to propagate a clone of the ancillary data into the GIS database, and use the database to do the join/subselect.

Comment: ahh yea currently I just pull in a few years of data that I know will contain the records I need then do a join, but was hoping I could just add the filter to the query directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a join over two databases if the are on the same MS SQL-Server, ex.

```
SELECT 
tb_1.*,
tb_2.*
FROM [database_1].[table_schema].[table_name_1] tb_1
JOIN [database_2].[table_schema].[table_name_2] tb_2 ON tb_1.id = tb_2.id
```

you need the permission to access the database and the specified table

Comment: Unfortunately they are on different servers

Comment: no problem please read: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)